# Google cloud function: SocketConnectNonbillable Quota exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm using google cloud functions that hitting the external API (in my case Amazon API).
It worked fine couple of months without any code change and suddenly few days ago started to show errors:

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'NetworkEgressNonbillable' and limit 'Outgoing socket traffic per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'HIDDEN'....)

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'DNSResolutionsNonbillable' and limit 'DNS resolutions per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'HIDDEN'., Quota exceeded for quota group 'NetworkEgressNonbillable' and
> limit 'Outgoing socket traffic per 100 seconds' of service
> 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'HIDDEN'.)

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'SocketConnectNonbillable' and limit 'Socket connections per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'HIDDEN'., Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'DNSResolutionsNonbillable' and limit 'DNS resolutions per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'HIDDEN'., Quota exceeded for quota group
> 'NetworkEgressNonbillable' and limit 'Outgoing socket traffic per 100
> seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'HIDDEN'.)

On the quotas page, I see that it's unlimited (see the example in the attached screenshot)
[image]

**The credit card is attached and billing is active**.

The question is: what happened and how to fix it. Cause seems I fall into some quota limits and hence cannot request the API endpoint, due to unable to resolve the URL (Amazon api URL in my case).

Comment: Per the error message you are getting I would say that you breached some free quota for your Cloud Functions, however I believe that this question should be asked for [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) since they are specialists in the subject and can give you a proper guidance if billing is misconfigured or if this is an issue with the billing in your project itself.

Comment: @RafaelLemos as I said it worked for several months okay with enabled billing and I paid for GCF as well as for other services were used, like gcs, gbq, cloud tasks queue, etc... Thanks for a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There appeared to be an internal (google's) issue that caused this one and according to engineers, a fix was rolled out for it.